# Varargs methods warning

Tags: android, suppress-warnings

I have this doInBackground in my async task and I'm getting this Vargas warning :

> Varargs methods should only override or be overridden by other varargs methods unlike RingBankAsyncTask.doInBackground(String[]) and AsyncTask.doInBackground(String...)

```
   protected String doInBackground(String[] urls){
   String result = "";
   for (int i = 0; i <= 0; i++){
     result = invokePost(urls[i], this.postData);
   }
   return result;
 }
```

I know why I'm getting this warning but Is there a workaround to get rid of this !?

Comment: What warning? All I see is your code.

Comment: @MikeM. I've edited my question

Comment: You should check the actual declaration for `AsyncTask.doInBackground()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
protected String doInBackground(String[] urls)
```

to

```
protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
```

varargs means a varying length of arguments, so although you use it like an array on the receiving end, you supply params like the following (if you were manually calling the method):

```
doInbackground(val1, val2, val3);
```

vs

```
doInbackground(new String[] { val1, val2, val3 });
```

*As a rule, you can always look at the supertype when overriding a method to make sure you match it's signature, and for many other useful things with other problems too. Just make sure you have sources installed.*

Comment: You can improve your answer by explaining how this resolves the error message.